# os.chdir returns directory with double slashes

Tags: python

I've searched and found solutions to this problem when the os.chdir() contains an actual path in quotes, but I'm trying to use a variable.

```
scriptpath = os.path.realpath(__file__)
codeScriptPath = os.chdir(scriptpath)
```

The error message received looks a little something like:

```
"F:\\path\\path\\path\\path\\main.py"
```

Not sure how to fix the error and can't find anything hoping I can get some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify your side point, you are confusing the CONTENTS of a string with the way it is REPRESENTED.  Your string does NOT contain any double-backslashes.  Python displays single backslashes as doubled in error messages so it can display newlines as "\n".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error doesn't have to do with double slashes (that's how python escapes backslash in a string).  Your error has to do with trying to change directory to a path that points to a file.  You probably want something like the below instead:

```
scriptpath = os.path.realpath(__file__)
d = os.path.dirname(scriptpath)
os.chdir(d)
```

The call to `os.path.dirname` will return the path of the directory that contains `scriptpath`.

Comment: Nvm about this comment, I figured it out thanks for the help.

Comment: Please post a complete snippet that you need help with.